# chef upload cookbook failed with network error

Tags: chef, knife, cookbook

I've created a chef server on a virtual machine (192.168.0.21).
The server runs fine on https (this is the last version from the opscode site).

`knife user list` (and the other list commands) run fine, returning the right results (all the users/nodes/clients. new users shows just fine).

when I'm trying to upload a cookbook to the server, I'm getting this error:

> Network Error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
>   Check your knife configuration and network settings

or this longer error:

> ERROR: Network Error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
>   Check your knife configuration and network settings
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in`open'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in`timeout'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in`connect'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in`start'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in`execute'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/resource.rb:76:in`put'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:153:in `block in uploader_function_for'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:25:in`call'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in setup_worker_threads'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:24:in`loop'
>       from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.8.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in setup_worker_threads'

the knife.rb file:

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'dony'
client_key               '/home/dony/.chef/dony.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '/home/dony/Documents/cd/cv.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://192.168.0.21'
syntax_check_cache_path  '/home/dony/.chef/syntax_check_cache'
cookbook_path   [ "/home/dony/Documents/chef" ]
```

Since other commands to the server are working, I can't put my finger on that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it appears that it is the server fault. 
server FQDN should be set on the server side.

1. edit `/etc/hostname`, to e.g. `yourhost.dyndns.org`
2. run: `hostname -F /etc/hostname`

thats all

Comment: @MikeFiedler
$ knife cookbook list
apt                  2.6.1
awesome_customers    0.1.0
firewall             1.5.2
httpd                0.2.19
learn_chef_apache2   0.2.1
poise                2.3.2
This means my knife configuration is Ok .... & $ hostname
ashishk.example.com .....this shows network settings is also Ok ....Still getting error ERROR: Network Error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Check your knife configuration and network settings

Answer (score 0):

You may have come across a weird bug in either Chef or it's underlying library, rest-client.

In Chef 11.10.alpha, this may have been [replaced/fixed](https://github.com/opscode/chef/commit/43427bf41bcf07a04946b0a7435af78ec4955426) already.

You might also try to specify the actual port in `knife.rb`, like so:

```
chef_server_url          'https://192.168.0.21:443'
```

This might help the current library interpret the location correctly.

Comment: the chef_server_url is configure correctly in the knife.rb file, otherwise I won't be able to run command to the server (e.g. list).
I don't know if a client.rb will help, but I'll definitely try that.
Thank you anyway, and I'll update here for any results.

Comment: BTW setting this on the knife.rb did nothing. I'm still getting to the server, but can't upload.

Comment: Sorry. This solution is not helping. thanks for your time